# Tabular form controls HTML css

Tags: html, css

I am making a simple (ha!) table.  There are problems with what I've included that I would like to fix.

1. I would like the left hand edges of the input fields to line up.  The checkbox and button don't.
2. I would like to vertically center the text in the labels w.r.t. the associated text input controls.
3. I would like to avoid the 12em margin on the final submit button.

Thanks.  Any ideas appreciated.

```css
    p {
      text-align: center;
    }
    p label {
      float: left;
      clear: left;
      width: 20em;
      text-align: right;
      margin: .25em 1em 0em 0em;
      padding: .25em;
    }
    p label input {
      float: right;
      clear: right;
      padding: .25em;
    }
    #submit {
      clear: both;
      float: left;
      margin: 1em 0em 0em 12em;
      clear: left;
      width: 6em;
      text-align: center;
      background: yellow;
    }
    p > input {
      text-align: center;
    }
    span {
      padding: 0em 1em 0em 0em;
    }
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <p>
      <label><span>Name:</span>
        <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" autofocus required>
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label><span>Password:</span>
        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label><span>Are you a photographer?:</span>
        <input id="photog" type="checkbox">
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Register">
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you provide a Fiddle or an image of how your desired result should look like?

Comment: @pbaldauf why should he? You have the snippet right inside the question. You can go and create one with the provided code.

Comment: @Len `p label input {padding: .25em;}` (remove floats and clears) will align vertically. Not sure what you want regarding the left alignment... Actually you should explain better the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't do everything you want but it's a start. I've taken `<input>` elements outside of the `<label>` elements allowing the `<label>`s to get a fixed width by adding `display: inline-block`. I also gave the `<label>`s a `for` attribute to keep them linked to their corresponding `<input>` field. By adding an empty `<label>` in front of the submit button it gets the proper layout.

In general it's a good idea to use `float` as little as possible and to style using classes instead of styling the html elements directly. I personally always look at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) (in this case its [forms styling](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)) to see how they do it.

```css
label {
  width: 11em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: .25em;
  padding: .25em;
}
input {
  padding: .25em;
}
#submit {
  margin: 1em 0em;
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <p>
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" autofocus required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="photog">Are you a photographer?:</label>
      <input id="photog" type="checkbox">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label></label>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Register">
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a table (ha!) in the first place.

Consider using: http://jsfiddle.net/qy911wrb/

```
<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
```

has been added and some CSS was adjusted that you requested.
Please indicate if there should be any other visual adjustments.